# Including empty k/v pairs when merging hashes

Tags: ruby, hashtable

There are three hashes. Each hash results in a single key/value pair.

When merged and outputted to a json file, the only k/v pairs visible are the ones with data.

For example:

```
employee_hours[ name ] =         {"Hours" => hours}
employee_revenue [ name ] =      {"Revenue" => revenue}
employee_activations [ name ] =  {"Activations" => activations}
```

If any of the k/v pairs don't exist I need them to be included in the output with a value of `0.00`.

I tried to simply just include empty k/v pairs from the other hashes in each hashtable, but when merged, they overwrite existed values.

```
employee_hours[ name ] =         {"Hours" => hours, "Revenue" = "", Activations = ""}
employee_revenue [ name ] =      {"Hours" => "", "Revenue" => revenue, Activations = ""}
employee_activations [ name ] =  {"Hours" => "", "Revenue" => "", "Activations" => activations}
```

**Edit**

My current code is listed here: https://gist.github.com/hnanon/766a0d6b2b0f9d9d03fd

Comment: Have you tried directly assigning the zero values to them? From what I know, a Ruby hash's k/v pair will only be output if it has been directly referenced at least once.

Comment: Just tried that...still not working. The first two hashes are merged with the third (`employee_activation`) and it seems like the third is overwriting the values from the other two.

Comment: What is your expected result? Where are you actually doing the merge?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a hash for the default values and merge into it. Assuming that employee_final is the hash where you merged all the employee information,

```
employee_defaults = { "Hours" => 0.0, "Revenue" => 0.0 }
employee_final.each_key do |name|
  employee_final[name] = employee_defaults.merge(employee_final[name])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you need to define a 'REQUIRED_KEYS' array, and add check on their existence in your hashes. Here's one way to achieve that:

```
REQUIRED_KEYS = [ "A", "B", "C" ]
DEFAULT_VALUE = 0.0    
REQUIRED_KEYS.each { |key| your_hash[key] = DEFAULT_VALUE if not your_hash.has_key?(key) }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Hash Defaults

You can use an argument to [Hash#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) to set a default value for a hash. For example:

```
require 'json'

employee_hours       = Hash.new(0.0)
employee_revenue     = Hash.new(0.0)
employee_activations = Hash.new(0.0)

name = 'Bob'

{
  'Hours'       => employee_hours[name],
  'Revenue'     => employee_revenue[name],
  'Activations' => employee_activations[name],
}.to_json

# => "{\"Hours\":0.0,\"Revenue\":0.0,\"Activations\":0.0}"
```

Comment: Please see gist in edited question. I don't think you're setup will work for what I have.